# Using Marker interface for making methods more generic

Tags: java

For example,

I have a method in an abstract class with the following signature.

```
Set<CarRecommendation> generateRecommendations(String accountId){

  // do something

}
```

To make the above method generic and compatible for different types of Recommendation, I'm thinking of using an empty interface and let CarRecommendation and BikeRecommendation implement it.

```
public interface Recommendation {

}


public class CarRecommendation implements Recommendation{

    // more stuff 
}

public class BikeRecommendation implements Recommendation{

    // more stuff
}
```

so that I can change the method signature in the abstract class to the following

```
Set<? extends Recommendation> generateRecommendations(String accountId)
```

Is it a good practice to define marker interfaces for the sole purpose of making methods generic? If not, what would be a better approach? Thanks.

Comment: This is **not** a `marker`.

Comment: A "marker interface" is one that does not contain any methods - see `Serializable`. If `Recommendation` contains any methods, then it is not a marker. If `CarRecommendation` and `BikeRecommendation` have similar implementations, then move that into `Recommendation`

Comment: @Strikegently I just edited the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the returned `Set`? If you use a marker interface, you won't be able to do anything with the elements of the set, except invoking `Object`'s method, i.e. `toString()`

Comment: planning to create a stream out of it and may be some filtering operations on it. Would you mind explaining why I won’t be able to do anything on it? I must be missing something.